# js - Filter out attribute based on key

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda

I have a `js` *variable* like:

> var mylist = [[   {item: 'emp', pos:1},   {age: 21, name: 'AA'},
>     {age: 22, name: 'BB'}, ], ... ];

in my `js` script, I read

```
var out = (mylist[0].map(function(i, j){return i.age}))
total = out.length   // this has 3 -->  ['', '21', '22']
```

How do I filter out elements in the list and just return the ones with `age` keyword, so my 
total would be  =  ['21', '22']

I am new to `js`, so not sure how to handle the *?lambda?* function to add a condition or filter out/ return *"clean"* data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) after [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to remove those `undefined` values.

```js
var mylist = [[ {item: 'emp', pos:1}, {age: 21, name: 'AA'}, {age: 22, name: 'BB'}]];

var out = mylist[0].map(i => i.age).filter(age => age);

console.log(out);
```

Comment: is that `js`? what langyage is that, scala?

Comment: @Lou_Ds - It is JavaScript. I'm using [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) introduced in ES6. You can also use regular functions like you did in the question.

Comment: You should `filter first and then map`, so you need to loop on less values when you map if there are entries without age

Comment: That's right @CodeManiac. Thanks for pointing it out. I think `reduce()` would be ideal here because then we only need to loop once.